# Getting key from Dictionary into neasted Decodable model

Tags: swift, decodable

Let's say we have a JSON like that:

```
{
  "id1": {
    "name": "hello"
  },
  "id2": {
    "name": "world"
  }
}
```

A model:

```
struct Model: Decodable {
  var id: String
  var name: String
}
```

How is it possible to make an array of `Model` from the JSON above?

Comment: Using a custom `init(from:)` and an unkeyed container is one way. Using JSONSerialization to get a dictionary that you map into Model objects is another

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
let data = """
{
  "id1": {
    "name": "hello"
  },
  "id2": {
    "name": "world"
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!


struct Name: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

struct Model {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

do {
    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Name].self, from: data)
    let result = json.map { Model(id: $0.key, name: $0.value.name) }
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

We decode the data as `[String, Name]`. We could decode it as `[String: [String:String]]` but this will mean that we will have to handle optional values so it is easier to create a `Name` struct to handle that part.

Once we have the dictionary we map over it converting it into the model object, leaving an array of `[Model]`